# How do I check the status of the CMOS battery?

Tags: battery, monitoring

I have found myself in situtations where the internal battery has been used frequently. How do I check its status without diving into the mountain of directories?

**NOTE** I need to know about the CMOS battery. not the laptop's power supply, so this isn't a duplicate of those questions

Comment: If you mean the [CMOS battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery), please update your question and its title to say so – “internal” is a rather puzzling term, as laptop batteries are usually internal.

Comment: Just a link cuz this is probably what you need: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/nvram.4freebsd.html But nooooooooo idea how since it differs per system .... Edit about close votes removed; If you have complaints post that on https://meta.askubuntu.com/ and otherwise: after it is closed it can be re-opened

Answer (score 11):

```
$ cat /proc/driver/rtc | grep batt
batt_status     : okay
```

Comment: Relevant note: "CMOS" is a tiny bit of very low power static memory that lives on the same chip as the Real-Time Clock. It is fairly convenient to actually think of the RTC as being "part" of CMOS. -- [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS)

Comment: Tried this after removing the CMOS battery: this command still stays `batt_status: okay`

Answer (score 9):

use app `lm_sensors`:

```
$ sensors-detect
```

next , run `sensors` and look for `Vbat` value:

```
$ sensors
it8718-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +1.18 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:          +1.89 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +3.31 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
+5V:          +2.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +0.69 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in5:          +0.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in6:          +0.42 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in7:          +2.93 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:         +2.94 V  
fan1:        1713 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:        1558 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +48.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +39.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +70.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:         -2.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +55.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +56.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +55.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: And which of those figures is the CMOS battery?

Comment: This screen: 
Vbat:         +2.94 V    
but your system it may be Battery or another, all depends from modules detected in sensors-detect

Comment: I tried that, I get multiple temp sensors and fan status. Nothing on voltages.

Answer (score 5):

If you open up the laptop, you can use a multimeter to check the voltmeter reading of the CMOS battery. This is the only reliable way that I know of.

Comment: My system reported `batt_status` okay via `/proc/driver/rtc` but when I measured with voltmeter only 0.2V

Answer (score 4):

The `sensors` command doesn't output the CMOS battery voltage for my laptop. This article gives other pointers:

- [The Signs of a Bad CMOS Battery](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/the-signs-of-a-bad-cmos-battery)

To summarize the link:

> A constant beeping sound is another sign that your CMOS battery is
>   dying. The final sign that your CMOS battery is going dead is that
>   you'll receive an error message. The three main types of error
>   messages are: CMOS Checksum Error, CMOS Read Error and CMOS Battery
>   Failure.