# Is there a way to check the bios battery from the command line?

Tags: command-line, battery, bios, firmware

Is there a way to check the bios battery life from the command line?

Comment: If there's information you're looking for beyond what's available [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946027/how-do-i-check-the-status-of-the-cmos-battery), then please [edit] this question with details. (Feel free also to ping me if you like.)