# Occasional problems booting my NUC - CMOS error

Tags: boot

Yes, it is "old" and the battery may be getting flat, but I'm not sure that is the problem.

I have an Intel NUC.
Intel NUC 7i5BNH  32 Gig of memory.

And ok:  The BIOS (or what ever it is now called) isn't up to date.

The story:
Now and then when I boot, the NUC "reboots" a few times before I see anything happening on the screen.
USUALLY I see a couple of things happening, then the GUI loads.
But when it *fails* the LED/lights come on.   Time passes.  Lights go from *ON* to *STANDBY* colour.   Then back to *ON*, *STANDBY*, *ON*, *STANDBY* then *ON* and it boots.

I get a messages (very quickly) CMOS error the screen is wiped and things boot.
For a quick time the clock is MARCH 01:58 (from memory)  Then it changes to the correct time.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Before you ask:
It is not predictable.   I used this machine last night and when I booted it today it did it.
Yet other times I have not turned the machine on for one and a half days and it doesn't *fail* on boot.

Comment: Actually that does sound like a battery is going bad.  The NUC MB could possibly be storing enough power for moment in the capacitors to help keep the BIOS info saved.  Also, as long as there is power flowing into the NUC MB it may keep those settings.  If the system does not have power connected to it and you try to power it on it can drain all capacitance and reset the BIOS back.  As far as the time getting set to the correct time during boot that can be due to NTP protocols running.  To me it really sounds like your battery is very weak or bad.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1181013/231142

Comment: Greatest apologies:  When I turn the NUC OFF, it is turned **OFF** - NO power at all.

Comment: As this may be the problem: when I'm done here/now I'll open the NUC up and see what I can find.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.
SOLVED.
Bought new battery, dismantled NUC, replaced and now things are working.
Now, how do I mark this as SOLVED?

Comment: You can actually answer your own below as a Q&A style and put in that the battery replacement fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dismantled the NUC, changed the battery and it is now all good.
Thanks to all for their replies/help.